# Iterate through model instance variables in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Consider a model defined as below:

```
class ProblemVerificationModel(CreateUpdateDateModel):
    problem = models.ForeignKey(Problem, related_name="problem_survey")
    verifier = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="verified_problem")

    is_problem_properly_formated = ... # BooleanField
    some_field = ... #BooleanField
    some_other_field = ... #BooleanField
```

I need to find sum of all integer-like values (`True`->1, `False`->0) of a `ProblemVerificationModel` model instance. I can add these values by accessing each field using `instance.field` and add them all. However, I want to know if there is more clean way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suppose writing a method that does it would be more Pythonic. And unless necessary, I wouldn't use a dynamic list for the fields to be used, since you don't make changes to a model very frequently.

```
class ProblemVerificationModel(CreateUpdateDateModel):
    ...
    is_problem_properly_formated = ... # BooleanField
    ...

    def get_bool_sum(self):
        bool_fields = (
            'is_problem_properly_formated',
            'some_field',
            'some_other_field',
        )
        return sum(bool(getattr(self, field)) for field in bool_fields)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Meta API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/meta/) of the model in order to dynamically collect all `Integer-` and `BooleanFields` and subtypes thereof:

```
class ProblemVerificationModel(CreateUpdateDateModel):
    #...

    def int_sum(self):
        return sum(
            getattr(self, f.name) or 0 for f in self._meta.get_fields() 
            if isinstance(f, (IntegerField, BooleanField))
        )
```